# PDF Asian character support - JasperReports

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, jasper-reports, asianfonts

I am trying to provide Asian character support for PDF documents created using Jasper Reports.

I have tried configuring jasper to use Asian character encoding with the iText-Asian libraries to no avail. For all of the different charsets I used the Asian characters always appear blank.

Has anyone successfully configured jasper reports to displayed Asian characters in PDF documents? If so How?!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Font Extensions are the answer to everything. Well, at least they are the answer to this.

I wrote an article about [font extensions](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/jaspersoft-v3-7-font-extensions/). It shows specifically the case of Asian characters not showing up in the generated PDF, which appears to be your main symptom. By doing that you're sure to use a good font. And once you're using an appropriate font, then all your reports should be fine.